# Localhost request from angular

Tags: python, angular, flask

Hello i have created a mini endpoint in Flask in python, and it's working well. When i access it from Postman :

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/retrieve_data`

it retrieves the data as a json.
    But when i call the endpoint from angular:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-demo';
  data = this.getAnnounce();

  getAnnounce() {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/retrieve_data');
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
```

The actual result is:

```
    {
        "_isScalar": false,
        "source": {
            "_isScalar": false,
            "source": {
                "_isScalar": false,
                "source": {
                    "_isScalar": true,
                    "value": {
                        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/retrieve_data",
                        "body": null,
                        "reportProgress": false,
                        "withCredentials": false,
                        "responseType": "json",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "headers": {
                            "normalizedNames": {},
                            "lazyUp
Canceldate": null,
                            "headers": {}
                        },
                        "params": {
                            "updates": null,
                            "cloneFrom": null,
                            "encoder": {},
                            "map": null
                        },
                        "urlWithParams": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/retrieve_data"
                    }
                },
                "operator": {
                    "concurrent": 1
                }
            },
            "operator": {}
        },
        "operator": {}
    }
```

PS: i am very noob at anuglar

Comment: which http client do you use? please show the import

Answer (score 2):

From the [document of angular's http client](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get), the return value's type of `http.get()` is `Observable`

So if you want to get the data that you server respond, you must subscribe as this:

```
data = {};

getAnnounce() {
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/retrieve_data')
        .subscribe(result => this.data = result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and as some others have suggested it would seem that you're missing a `.subscribe()` on your `getAnnounce()` method. [Angular Docs has a guide on observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) that can help you get a better understanding.

I have a few more suggestions for improving your experience with angular. Take advantage of [services](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services) for grouping together similar functionality. For example, in your provided code, you could move your `getAnnounce()` to a new service you create; something like `AnnouncementService`. Then you can use this in many places of your code. it also helps test it and find bugs later on since your code is more separated.

Another thing you can do is to move your server api address to the environment variables. By default if you built your angular project using the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) you'll find in our src folder an `environments` folder with two files by default `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`. you can access this JSON object anywhere within your .ts files and when you build your code for product vs locally it can change values to what ever you set. In your case you would put your local API address in there `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
};
```

Now you can access this easily and have one spot to change if you ever change your port number or have your api in a real server.

> import { environment } from './environments/environment';
>
> /* remember to import the non prod version of the environment file, angular knows how to switch them automatically when building for production or not. */

Hopefully this helps you with your coding, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to your `getAnnounce` function.

For instance, you can try:

```
data = this.getAnnounce().subscribe();
```

Or directly on your `constructor` / `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getAnnounce().subscribe(
     data => this.data = data
   );
}
```

Comment: I believe doing this `data = this.getAnnounce().subscribe();` would set `data` to subscription not the data return. This is how you can store a reference of something subscribed to be able to unsubscribe later on. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription for more information on subscriptions :)